# PHP Mysql insert mathematical formula into database

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create a simple PHP web system to “view”, “add”, “edit” and “delete” loan applications. The problem is during add new loan records to the system because i need to calculate formula for calculating "home loan" installment amount

The formula :

[image]

amount and duration is fetch during user fill up the form

[image]

Question : How i do mathematical operation to calculate installment amount from what user fill in the form to insert in mysql database? Thanks

Comment: This is a multi–part problem: getting the input, performing the calculation, and storing the result. Which part do you need help with?

Comment: thx for your reply , i need to perform the calculation and also storing the result

Comment: show your research too..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps.

```
<?php
$interest=0.5;

$amt=$_POST['amount'];
$duration=$_POST['duration']; // duration is in months

$intamt=pow((1+$interest),$duration);

$intamt2=pow((1+$interest),($duration-1));

$installment=($amt*0.5*$intamt)/$intamt2;

echo $installment;


?>
```

Check the working example here(http://codepad.org/Fw3wbsUP)